# Google federation and server to server encryption

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

I am trying to set up an XMPP server, such that users of my service can communicate with XMPP users of other services.  I have two requirements

1) Users of other services must still be able to use whatever client and chat service they are currently using, such as the gmail web client, to talk to my clients.

2) The communication must be encrypted when sent between client and server and server and server. (The later is more difficult)

I setup an XMPP server and federated with gmail, and found that the server to server communications was not encrypted.  I next federated my XMPP server with jabber.org, and the connection from my server to jabber.org was encrypted, giving me confidence that my server configuration was correct.  Is there any way to encrypt the communication between my XMPP server and Google's   Are there any XMPP servers that support TLS with Google   Presuming this is not currently supported by Google, are their plans to add TLS on server to server communications in the future?  When is it expected?

In lieu of encrypted server to server communications, are there other possibilities (given the above requirements)?   Would a Google app engine application have encrypted communication between the gmail server and my Google app engine app and also satisfy the first requirement?

Answer (score 1):

For the communication server to server, you can use AES to encrypt all the communication, and for the password, you can send it with RSA. If you are using python you can use pycrypto, although to test it in the development server have to install that library.

About the client and server comunitacion I'm not sure if you can use the same encryption.

Comment: What type of server would you be using to talk to google talk and encrypt the communications?  I believe that by doing federation with google the server to server communication cannot be encrypted.  I do believe that the client to server communication is encrypted.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have not been on the computer several days. I've never used google talk (for that), but i've readed that google talk use OTR encryption. You can find more information, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk there is a section of encryption